# How to split a file (with sed) into numerous files according to a value found on each line?

Tags: sed, split

I have several `Company_***.csv files` (altough the separator's a tab not a comma; hence should be *.tsv, but never mind) which contains a header plus numerous data lines e.g

```
1stHeader   2ndHeader   DateHeader  OtherHeaders...
111111111   SOME STRING 2020-08-01  OTHER STRINGS..
222222222   ANOT STRING 2020-08-02  OTHER STRINGS..
```

I have to split them according to the 3rd column here, it's a date.

Each file should be named like e.g. `Company_2020_08_01.csv` `Company_2020_08_02.csv` & so one
and containing: same header on the 1st line + matching rows as the following lines.

At first I thought about saving (once) the header in a single file e.g.

```
 sed -n '1w Company_header.csv' Company_*.csv
```

then parsing the files with a pattern for the date (hence the headers would be skipped) e.g.

```
sed -n '/\t2020-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\t/w somefilename.csv' Company_*.csv
```

... and at last, insert the (missing) header in each generated file.

But I'm stuck at step 2: I can't find how I could generate (*dynamically*) the "filename" expected by the `w` command, neither how to capture the date in the search pattern (because apparently this is just an *address*, not a search-replace "field" as in the `s/regexp/replacement/[flags]` command, so you can't have capturing groups `( )` in there).

So I wonder if this is actually doable with `sed`? Or should I look upon other tools e.g. `awk`?

Disclaimer: I'm quite a n00b with these commands so I'm just learning/starting from scratch...

Comment: Should the `***` part in the original file names be ignored?

Comment: @choroba oh yeah totally, because it's basically the names of the months (files are monthly dumps of some sort of financial operations) and as I have to create daily files, the month names do not matter and will be discarded.

Comment: Are the lines ordered by the date?

Comment: @choroba per file, I think but I have not guarantee about that, and that's not something I would assume to write my script on. Does it matter?

Comment: It would simplify the solution, but it's OK. How many lines per file?

Comment: roundly ~50k-70k each

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -e 'while (<>) {
    $h = $_, next if $. == 1;
    $. = 0 if eof;
    @c = split /\t/;
    open my $out, ">>", "Company_" . $c[2] =~ tr/-/_/r . ".csv" or die $!;
    print {$out} $h unless tell $out;
    print {$out} $_;
}' -- Company_*.csv
```

- The diamond operator `<>` in scalar context reads a line from the input.
- The first line of each file is stored in the variable `$h`, see [$.](https://perldoc.pl/perlvar#$.) and [eof](http://p3rl.org/eof)
- [split](http://p3rl.org/split) populates the `@c` array by the column values for each line
- `$c[2]` contains the date, using `tr` we translate dashes to underscores to create a filename from it. [open](https://perldoc.pl/functions/open) opens the file for appending.
- [print](http://p3rl.org/print) prints the header if the file is empty (see [tell](http://p3rl.org/tell))
- and prints the current line, too.

Note that it only appends to the files, so don't forget to delete any output files before running the script again.

Comment: nice, but my question was targeted specifically on using `sed`, which apparently seems impossible... also I don't get in your script where it "splits" by the date.

Comment: btw as I had so little time to do this, I finally remembered my *nix courses at the Uni and we also used `awk` at that time (that was ~20 years ago)... so quickly learned a bit about it, trying to decypher the GNU manual https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html and so, and bingo! awk handles particularly well "records" (i.e. separated-value fields), so within a few hours I came up 
 with something quite similar to your perl script (or I think, at least it did the job - might post it here for posterity) :p

Comment: Yes, Perl borrows heavily from awk.